# Validação de E-mail em form na JSP

Tags: javascript, java, html5, jsp

Estou tentando fazer uma validação de um form de uma JSP através de JavaScript mas não estou conseguindo aplicar o Script corretamente, o que estou fazendo errado?

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>

<SCRIPT>
//teste de script
window.alert("teste, funcionando!")
/*função valida email*/
function verificarEEnviar()
{
    var dsEmail=document.captacaoEmailsForm[dsEmail].value;
    var atpos=dsEmail.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=dsEmail.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=dsEmail.length)
        {
            alert("Não é um endereço de e-mail válido");
            return false;
        }
    return document.captacaoEmailsForm.submit();

}
</SCRIPT>

<div class="captacao">
    <html:form action="/captacaoEmails" styleId="cadastroCliente2"> 
    <div class="captacao-titulo">Cadastre-se e receba<span> ofertas exclusivas </span> </div>
    <div class="captacao-email"> 
        <html:text tabindex="5" property="dsEmail" maxlength="60"/><html:errors property="dsEmail" header="empty"/>
        <a href="javascript:verificarEEnviar();" id="btContinuar" class="captacao fr">Enviar</a>
    </div>
    </html:form>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é o link:

```
<a href="javascript:document.captacaoEmailsForm.submit(); javascript:verificar" id="btContinuar" class="captacao fr">Enviar</a>
```

Você está enviando um formulário e só depois "chamando a função verificar" que nem existe! Tenta o contrário...

muda o link para

```
javascript:verificarEEnviar()
```

E o script ...

```
<SCRIPT>
//teste de script
window.alert("teste, funcionando!")
/*função valida email*/
function verificarEEnviar()
{
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
        {
            alert("Não é um endereço de e-mail válido");
            return false;
        }
    return document.forms["myForm"].submit();
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo vou testar, o "x" usado no JavaScript não tem de ter o mesmo nome do meu campo E-mail no form?

Comment: nossa... eu nem me atentei... o nome do formulário e do campo também precisam ser corrigidos! Dá uma olhada no código fonte do HTML e muda o nome das variáveis. É mais fácil.

Comment: mas tenho um problema, o campo e-mail só tem o property="dsEmail", quando tento inserir um id ou um name ele me trás erro, tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso? Não manjo muito de JSP, sou iniciante no Java então desculpe se alguma pergunta parecer besta ^^

Comment: Só posso mudar os nomes das variáveis no Script por que o form está funcionando certinho na parte do JAVA

Comment: Faz o seguinte... vá na página que foi gerada e veja o código fonte. Todo o código jsp é convertido para html que o seu browser interpreta. Usa o nome que foi gerado pelo jsp. provavelmente o property vai dar o nome para o input text field do email. Olha lá.

Comment: fui no HTML, encontrei os nomes que falou e substitui onde achei que fosse certo, mas ao clicar no botão de envio nada acontece e continua salvando no banco qualquer dado inserido, substitui corretamente no Script??

Comment: Atualiza o código na pergunta... =)

Comment: Pronto, atualizei :)

Comment: Quase lá... essa linha está errada...

        var dsEmail=document.captacaoEmailsForm[dsEmail].value;

dsEmail aqui deveria estar entre aspas senão vai ser o objeto dsEmail que está null.

Comment: Funcionou cara, MUITO OBRIGADO..e consegui compreender meu erro, isso que é mais importante! Valeu :)